# Does the mission to conquer 9 territories in one turn require them to be occupied?

Tags: risk, risk-legacy

In Risk Legacy there is a mission to conquer 9 territories in one turn.

Do the territories need to be occupied by another player before you capture them to count towards this mission objective?

Comment: Missions aren't in the starter rules - should this whole question be in a spoiler block? It isn't a big spoiler though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the implications in the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad2886d1c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/00D721465056900B10A16E11F8F54E7F.pdf), in order to conquer a territory it needs to be occupied.

Conquering is only referred to on page 12 of the rules, which indicates that it is the action taken after successfully Attacking an occupied territory.

Occupying an empty territory is referred to as Expanding by the rulebook on page 10.